# How to add text on top of an image inside a cell?

Tags: c#, itext, cell

I have problem placing text on top of (not below) an image inside the cell.

My code looks this:

```
Image img = Image.GetInstance(imagePatch);
img.Alignment = Image.UNDERLYING;
img.ScaleToFit(img.Width, img.Height);
img.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(ptable.TotalWidth);
pcell.AddElement(img);
pcell.addElement(new Paragraph("text", font));
img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, ptable.TotalHeight);`
```

But the text shows under the image instead of on top of it.

What can I do? Is there any way to set the padding from image borders to text content?

Comment: Try to comment `img.SetAbsolutePosition()`.

Comment: I did, nothing happened :(

Comment: Maybe you have to use `DirectContentUnder`? See [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/BackgroundImage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to achieve what you want, depending on the actual requirement.

**Approach 1:**

The first approach is explained in the [WatermarkedImages1](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/WatermarkedImages1) example. In this example, we create a `PdfTemplate` to which we add an image as well as some text written on top of that image. We can then wrap this `PdfTemplate` inside an image and add that image together with its watermark to a cell.

This is the method that performs all the magic:

```
public Image getWatermarkedImage(PdfContentByte cb, Image img, String watermark) throws DocumentException {
    float width = img.getScaledWidth();
    float height = img.getScaledHeight();
    PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(width, height);
    template.addImage(img, width, 0, 0, height, 0, 0);
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(template, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
            new Phrase(watermark, FONT), width / 2, height / 2, 30);
    return Image.getInstance(template);
}
```

**Approach 2.a**

The second approach is explained in the [WatermarkedImages2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/WatermarkedImages2) example. In this case, we add each image to a `PdfPCell`. This `PdfPCell` will scale the image so that it fits the width of the page. To add the watermark, we use a cell event:

```
class WatermarkedCell implements PdfPCellEvent {
    String watermark;

    public WatermarkedCell(String watermark) {
        this.watermark = watermark;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
        PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
            new Phrase(watermark, FONT),
            (position.getLeft() + position.getRight()) / 2,
            (position.getBottom() + position.getTop()) / 2, 30);
    }
}
```

This cell event can be used like this:

```
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(IMAGE1), true);
cell.setCellEvent(new WatermarkedCell("Bruno"));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(IMAGE2), true);
cell.setCellEvent(new WatermarkedCell("Dog"));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(IMAGE3), true);
cell.setCellEvent(new WatermarkedCell("Fox"));
table.addCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(IMAGE4), true);
cell.setCellEvent(new WatermarkedCell("Bruno and Ingeborg"));
table.addCell(cell);
```

You will use this approach if all images have more or less the same size, and if you don't want to worry about fitting the images on the page.

**Approach 2.b:**

Instead of adding the text to the `TEXTCANVAS` of a cell event of a cell that contains an image, you can also add the image to the `BACKGROUNDCANVAS` of a cell event of a cell that contains the text.

**Heads up:** there is a risk that your question will be closed as a duplicate of [How to add text to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814958/pdf-vertical-postion-method-gives-the-next-page-position-instead-of-current-page)