# iText, order of creating and adding content

Tags: java, c#, itext

I am creating a PDF file, but have stumbled upon a problem. Below are the `iText` commands that are causing it.

```
document.Header = header;
document.Open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContentUnder; (getDirectContentUnder() for java)
```

`document` is of type `Document`; `writer` is a `PdfWriter` and `header` is of type `HeaderFooter`.

`iText` have same conditions for order of those commands and those are:

- `PdfWriter` cannot be used before opening the document
- header of the PDF will not be shown at all, if I open the document before I add the header to it

That would be fine and I would write it in the order just like in the snippet above. But I need the `PdfWriter` for creating the header. And now I am in a loop:

- to create the header, I need to use `PdfWriter`
- to use `PdfWriter`, I need to open the document first
- for the header to be visible, I would need to create it before opening the document

Also, I found sources both for recommending the header to be created as the last thing **before** opening the document, as well as for recommending the header to be created **after** the document has been opened. Which is right and how to solve my problem?

**Update: Code**

```
BaseFont bf16 = BaseFont.CreateFont( "c:\\windows\\fonts\\Arial.ttf", BaseFont.CP1250, false );
Font fnt10Bold = new Font( bf16, 10, Font.BOLD, new Color( 100, 100, 100 ) );
System.Drawing.Bitmap headerBitmap = Properties.Resources.doc_header;
Image headerImg = Image.GetInstance( headerBitmap, Color.BLACK );

Document document = new Document( PageSize.A4, 36, 40, 20, 20 );
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance( document, new FileStream( path, FileMode.Create ) );

for ( int i = 0; i < DocList.Count; i++ )
{
    PdfPTable tblHeader = new PdfPTable( new float[] { 40, 60 } );
    tblHeader.WidthPercentage = 100;

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContentUnder;
    Image img = getWatermarkedImage( cb, headerImg, "Watermark", font10Bold );

    PdfPCell cellHeader = new PdfPCell( img, true ) { Colspan = 2
      HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
      VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM };
    tblHeader.AddCell( cellHeader );

    Phrase headerPhrase = new Phrase();
    headerPhrase.Add( tblHeader );

    document.Header = new HeaderFooter( headerPhrase, false );
    if ( i == 0 )
        document.Open();
    else
        document.NewPage();
}

document.Close();
```

`getWatermarkedImage` is the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817011) by Bruno Lowagie.

Comment: Java or C# ? I don't think your question is about both of them...

Comment: I use it on c#, but I wrote the syntax for java as well, since the solution should be the same for both, `iTextSharp` is just port of the `iText` from java.

Comment: And why the down vote, if I may ask?

Comment: There is no `HeaderFooter` class in any of the official versions of iText. Maybe you are using a third party class with that name; if so, show us that class. Maybe you're not using an official version of iText; in that case, I fear that the author of that unofficial version won't bother answering. In any case: I don't see a reason why you'd need an instance of `PdfWriter` to create a header, hence I can't help you. You should provide more information.

Comment: I use it for creating watermarked image, followed by your answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814958) question. And I use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL/4.1.6) version of `iTextSharp`.

Comment: Can you show some of your code, maybe there is a way to resolve the issue differently.

Comment: I updated the answer with some code.

Comment: I don't find a `Header` property in `Document`. You appear not to use a current iText 5 version (i.e. a 5.5.x) (nor do you use iText 7). One nowadays usually adds headers and footers with iText 5 by means of an instance of a `IPdfPageEvent` implementation (usually via the `PdfPageEventHelper` adapter) assigned to the `PageEvent` property of `PdfWriter`. The advantage in your case would be that the callback methods in that interface allow you to use the `PdfWriter` just-in-time, e.g. when the `OnEndPage` event is triggered. Thus, your hen-egg issue does not occur anymore.

Comment: Yes, I use 4.1.6 version, since that is the last version that can be used commercially, without open-sourcing your project.

Comment: Maybe there is a way of creating `PdfTemplate` object without the `PdfWriter`?

Comment: *"4.1.6 version, since that is the last version that can be used commercially, without open-sourcing your project"* - that is not entirely true, 5.x can be used in closed source projects if you buy a commercial license; only if you don't want to pay for the PDF expertise in that library, you are restricted by the AGPL.

Comment: That been said, as far as I remember 4.1.6 already supports page events. Thus, the solution for your issue is to use page events instead of those `HeaderFooter` classes.